# Create Fulltext index on decimal/number coloumn, possible????? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, numbers, fulltext-index

I'd like to create a fulltext index on several columns which are `varchars` and numbers. And there is the problem with the numbers.

Is there really no way to add column as number or decimal for the fulltext index?

I've got for example a table article:

```
CREATE TABLE article
(   articleid   number(10)  not null,
    articlename     varchar(50)     not null,
    articlecode1    varchar(50)
);

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MyCatalog;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON artikel
     (articleid LANGUAGE 0x0,
      articlename LANGUAGE 0x0,
      articlecode1 LANGUAGE 0x0)
KEY INDEX PK_ARTICLE ON MyCatalog
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

It couldn't be created, because `articleid` is a number!

My alternate solution is to create a second column such as `articleidtext varchar` as a copy of articleid. Afterward to fill up with a trigger.

Is there really no other way?

I've tried also to Cast like: `CAST(articleid AS varchar) LANGUAGE 0x0` it doesn't work either.

any other suggestion??

thx...

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a computed, persisted column of type `VARCHAR` based on your `articleId` - this doesn't need to be filled with a trigger or anything, it will always represent the `articleId`, but as a `VARCHAR` column, and thus it can be fulltext indexed:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.article
ADD ArticleIDText AS CAST(ArticleID AS VARCHAR(20)) PERSISTED
```

Now put your fulltext index on `ArticleIDText` and everything should be just fine....

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. Didn't thought about that, this is a good alternative to trigger. cheers robert

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Fulltext indexes on columns which are numbers. 
If you want to be able to search it using full text, u can convert the column to a string.

But the real question is are you looking for full text index or just a normal index!?

Answer (score 0):

fulltext works only with types :

char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, text, ntext, image, xml или varbinary(max)